# Imagerotate and then align with center of destination image

Tags: php, image, rotation

Right now my rotated image gets justified to the left and top of my destination image.  The behavior I want is for the center of the rotated image to be centered on the destination image.  The degree of rotation is dynamic.  The $center_pt is the center point of my destination.  I've been looking online for a day and a half but there must be a way!

```
$destination_image = 960; //960px x 960px
rotated image = 640px x 640px; // ($rotate & $rotate_me, same thing)
$center_pt = center of destination image

$rotate_me = imagecreatefrompng("myimage.png"); 
$rotate = imagerotate($rotate_me, $dynamicdegree),0);
imagesettile($im, $rotate);
imagefilledellipse($destination_image, $center_pt, $center_pt, $outer_outer_diameter, $outer_outer_diameter,     IMG_COLOR_TILED);
```

Sorry I prepared an image to share with you but did not have enough reputation to post it.

Answer (score 1):

It was difficult figuring out how to center my image after rotating it because it kept getting justified to the left.  Here's what I did, after stripping down a more verbose solution, works perfect!

```
  $src = imagerotate($rotate,$yournumber,$transColor); //rotated my image
  imagesavealpha($src, true); // alpha thing otherwise there was a black polygon around image

  //the rotation makes your image bigger, usually, so you need to find the new width and height

  $src_x = ImageSX($src); //find out new x width
  $src_y = ImageSY($src); //find out new y height

  $wantedWidth = 640;  //this is the width I want my completed image to be
  $wantedHeight = 640; //this is the height I want my completed image to be

  $src_widthx = $src_x/2 - $wantedWidth/2;  // divide each by 2 and then subtract desired end width from wider rotated width
  $src_heighty = $src_y/2 - $wantedHeight/2;  // and again for height

imagecopy($im, $src, 0, 0, $src_widthx, $src_heighty, 640, 640);  //notice I'm no longer using imagefilledellipse here as imagecopy seems to be more specifically for centering things
```